# What is ineffective or zero (0) range? (Identity element)

Tags: vba, excel, range, union

What is a `Range` that is ineffective (*identity element*), same as `0` in sum (+) operator?

`x + 0 = x`

*Update*:

Or same as `1` in multiplier (*) operator.

`x * 1 = x`

I need creating ineffective range, named `rng` as,

`Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ...`

So that in `Union()` function, been ineffective:

`rangex = Union(rangex, rng)`

Means summing (`Union`) of each ranges (for example `rangex`) with above `rng` (zero range), returns back that range (`rangex`), again.

**Some examples:**

1- ineffective value in datatype `Int` is: 0

2- ineffective value in datatype `String` is: ""

So I need ineffective value in datatype `Range`.

Comment: It is **Nothing**

Comment: ;-(;-(;-(;-(;-(;-(

Comment: what you are looking for is called the `identity element` ... for addition and subtraction the identity element is equal to zero. for multiplication and division it is equal to one. etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Union does not allow any parameters to be Nothing.

You can use the UDF below to achieve what you want.

For more information read [this](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/BetterUnion.aspx)

```
Function Union2(ParamArray Ranges() As Variant) As Range
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Union2
    ' A Union operation that accepts parameters that are Nothing.
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        Dim N As Long
        Dim RR As Range
        For N = LBound(Ranges) To UBound(Ranges)
            If IsObject(Ranges(N)) Then
                If Not Ranges(N) Is Nothing Then
                    If TypeOf Ranges(N) Is Excel.Range Then
                        If Not RR Is Nothing Then
                            Set RR = Application.Union(RR, Ranges(N))
                        Else
                            Set RR = Ranges(N)
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next N
        Set Union2 = RR
    End Function
```